# Como imprimo la lista de <select> en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select

Estoy haciendo un juego de carreras en JavaScript con HTML, en él, el jugador debe seleccionar a través de un  el numero de jugadores. Sin embargo no sé como hacer que se imprima el numero de veces que el jugador selecciona. Lo he hecho con un solo coche pero no me sale con varios. Adjunto codigo JS:

```
function num_jugadores(){
    var num= document.getElementById('numero');
    let valor = num.selectedIndex;

    escribe(valor+1);s
}
function escribe(valor){
    for(var i=1; i<valor+1; i++){
      document.body.innerHTML += "<div id = 'pista'>"
      document.body.innerHTML += "<img src='./img/car"+i+".png' id='coche"+i+"' class= 'coche'>"   
      document.body.innerHTML +="</div>"
    }
}
```

Adjunto codigo HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PAC Sergio Moreno</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
  
</head>
<body id ="carrera">
    <h1>Carrera de Coches</h1>

    <input type="button" value ="Empezar" id="start">
    <input type="button" value="Reiniciar" id="reset">

    <p>Selecciona el numero de jugadores: </p>
    <select name="selecciona" id="numero" onchange= "num_jugadores()">
        <option value="1" >1</option>
        <option value="2" >2</option>
        <option value="3" >3</option>
        <option value="4" >4</option>
        <option value="5" >5</option>
        <option value="6" >6</option>
        <option value="7" >7</option>
        <option value="8" >8</option>
        <option value="9" >9</option>
    </select>

    <script>
       num_jugadores();
    </script>

    <div id="informacion" class="tablero">
        <h2>Resultados</h2>
        <div id="infoCarrera1" class="infoCarrera">Coche 1<span></span></div>
       
    </div>

    <script src="jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Muchas gracias, un saludo.
La idea es que se vea en la pantalla una pista de carreras con el coche encima y al darle a Start empiece la carrera

Answer (score 1):

Primero, agrega esto en tu HTML, para ver el resultado de la cantidad de jugadores seleccionados:

```
<p id="jugadores-seleccionados">Jugadores seleccionados: 0</p>
```

Y en tu JS, inicializas una variable, en donde iremos asignando la cantidad de jugadores que se va a ir seleccionando, es decir, recibimos el valor del select y éste valor se asigna en tu variable, y el resultado final lo mostramos en el id `jugadores-seleccionados`, ejemplo:

```js
var num_jugadores_select = 0;

function num_jugadores(){
  var num = document.getElementById('numero'); // capturo al select...
  let valor = num.selectedIndex; // del select, capturo al value del option...
  num_jugadores_select = valor + 1; // ese value, lo guardo en "num_jugadores_select"...
  escribe(num_jugadores_select);
  document.getElementById("jugadores-seleccionados").textContent = "Jugadores seleccionados: " + num_jugadores_select; // y lo muestro en este id.
}

function escribe(valor){
  for(var i=1; i<valor+1; i++){
    document.body.innerHTML += "<div id = 'pista'>"
    document.body.innerHTML += "<img src='./img/car"+i+".png' id='coche"+i+"' class= 'coche'>"   
    document.body.innerHTML +="</div>"
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>PAC Sergio Moreno</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">

</head>
<body id ="carrera">
  <h1>Carrera de Coches</h1>

  <input type="button" value ="Empezar" id="start">
  <input type="button" value="Reiniciar" id="reset">

  <p>Selecciona el numero de jugadores: </p>
  <select name="selecciona" id="numero" onchange= "num_jugadores()">
    <option value="1" >1</option>
    <option value="2" >2</option>
    <option value="3" >3</option>
    <option value="4" >4</option>
    <option value="5" >5</option>
    <option value="6" >6</option>
    <option value="7" >7</option>
    <option value="8" >8</option>
    <option value="9" >9</option>
  </select>

  <p id="jugadores-seleccionados">Jugadores seleccionados: 0</p>

  <div id="informacion" class="tablero">
    <h2>Resultados</h2>
    <div id="infoCarrera1" class="infoCarrera">Coche 1<span></span></div>

  </div>

  <script src="jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```